# TeX and TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting, latex, display

I have a little problem, and hope, with your help, I'll be able to solve it.

As you got from the title, I have some trouble with TeX in Mathematica. Imagine, I want to output a nice DisplayFormula, such that it would represent a function, which evaluates piecewise. In TeX it would look like this (Let's take a uniform distribution for example)

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&0,& t\leq x_{\min} \\
&\frac{t-x_{\min}}{x_{\max}-x_{\min}},&x_{\min}<t\leq x_{\max} \\
&1,& t>x_{\max}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

So what's the best way to create that exact output in Mathematica?

I've tried `TraditionalForm[CDF[UniformDistribution[{x_ {min}, x_ {max}}], t]]`, but that gives me almost the same output, but without the zero part.

[image]

I do know, it's not significant whether to write or not the 0 part in the piecewise function.

So it works well for CDF, but with PDF there's an extraneous part is shown at the end

```
TraditionalForm[CDF[UniformDistribution[{x_ {min}, x_ {max}}], t]]
```

[image]

So in the CDF Mathematica's decided not to output the 0 part, but in the PDF it's shown.

I've also tried to use

```
TraditionalForm[
  Piecewise[
   {{0, t <= Subscript[x, min]},
    {(t - Subscript[x, min])/(Subscript[x, max] - Subscript[x, min]), 
     Subscript[x, min] < t <= Subscript[x, max]},
    {1, t > Subscript[x, max]}},
   t
  ]
]
```

But that variant also reveals the part that I haven't specified.

[image]

The last thing I've tried to use is `ToExpression["TeX source",TeXForm]`,  but this one can't parse the simple TeX source with aligned environment (or I haven't found a way to make it work).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the output, well, write it manually. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> gives you the piecewise bracket. Then you can insert a table (`Insert->Table/Matrix`) or learn the shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, etc.

I got this box structure. You can see the result by running.

```
RawBoxes@FormBox[
  RowBox[{"\[Piecewise]", 
    GridBox[{{RowBox[{"0", ","}], 
       RowBox[{"t", "\[LessEqual]", 
         SubscriptBox["x", "min"]}]}, {RowBox[{FractionBox[
          RowBox[{"t", "-", SubscriptBox["x", "min"]}], 
          RowBox[{SubscriptBox["x", "max"], "-", 
            SubscriptBox["x", "min"]}]], ","}], 
       RowBox[{SubscriptBox["x", "min"], "<", "t", "\[LessEqual]", 
         SubscriptBox["x", "max"]}]}, {RowBox[{"1", ","}], 
       RowBox[{"t", ">", SubscriptBox["x", "max"]}]}}]}], 
  TraditionalForm]
```

You can then style it further to suit you...

Comment: You're correct! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `\[AligmentMarker]` character. To help you better write equations, lets forget about the `DisplayFormula` style and lets create our own.

## Set up:

Let us create the style `DisplayMath`. In your notebook where you are writing your displayed equation go to `Format > Edit Stylesheet...`. Here you will create a new cell. Show the expression of the cell by going to `Cell > Show Expression` or by pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in a mac. Now enter the following in that expression:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayMath"],
    ConversionRules->{
        "TeX" -> {"$$\n", Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[#]& , "\n$$"}, 
        "HTML" -> {"$$\n", StringReplace[Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[#], {"<" -> " \\lt ", ">" -> " \\gt "}]& , "\n$$\n\n"}
    },
    DefaultFormatType->TraditionalForm,
    TextAlignment->Center,
    LanguageCategory->"Formula",
    AutoSpacing->True,
    ScriptLevel->0,
    AutoMultiplicationSymbol->False,
    SingleLetterItalics->True,
    SpanMaxSize->Infinity,
    CounterIncrements->"DisplayMath",
    FontFamily->"Times",
    FontSize->16,
    ShowInvisibleCharacters->All,
    UnderoverscriptBoxOptions->{LimitsPositioning->False},
    GridBoxOptions->{
    GridBoxAlignment->{
        "Columns" -> {{"\[AlignmentMarker]"}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
        "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}
    }
]
```

This is the style that I'm using to display mathematics. Notice the use of `ShowInvisibleCharacters`, this makes the `\[AligmentMarker]` to be displayed. If you do not wish for this to be displayed when you print or in a presentation then turn it off when you use another environment. You do so by creating a cell with these contents:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayMath", "Printout"],
    ShowInvisibleCharacters->None
]
```

The option `GridBoxOptions` simply say that the grids in this style will be aligned using
the `\[AlignmentMarker]`. Now lets type some math.

## Writing Aligned Equations:

Start by creating a cell using the `DisplayMath` style, you can do this by pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> in a mac use <kbd>alt</kbd> in windows and entering `DisplayMath`. Enter `a+b+c=d`. What we want now is to go one step down, we can do this by pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>. If you did this now you should see a box right below "d", we want a box to be below the whole expression. So delete that box, select the whole expression and try again. After that enter the following: `c=d-a-b`. This is what you should see now:

[image: not aligned]

To make them become aligned, now we can use the `\[AligmentMarker]`. We want them to be aligned along the equal signs we can enter <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> next to the equal signs. Now we should see this:

[image: aligned]

After you finish with a column, you can create another column by pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>. And repeat. Here is a display of your equation from your example:

[image: result]

To put the bracket I used what Rojo mentioned. I typed <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> at the beginning of the equation.

Comment: Nice method! How do you add equation numbers in your approach?

Comment: @yarchik Its been years since I've used Mathematica. I'm not sure if this still applies but back then I did ask a question related to equation numbers: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29332/numbered-equations-formulas The question was lated to LaTeX but maybe it can be combined with whatever I wrote here?