# How to write aligned equations and export them HTML/TeX

Tags: conversion

This question is mainly about exporting to HTML/TeX. For those of you who do not know how to write aligned equations in *Mathematica* please see this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6086/877). Lets assume that you modified your stylesheet as I mentioned in my answer. In my notebook this is the cell expression I have:

```
Cell[BoxData[
    FormBox[GridBox[{
    {
    RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"a", "+", "b", "+", "c"}], "\[AlignmentMarker]", "=", "d"}]},
    {
    RowBox[{"c", "\[AlignmentMarker]", "=", 
    RowBox[{"d", "-", "a", "-", "b"}]}]}
}], TraditionalForm]], "DisplayMath"]
```

Now I want to export this expression to TeX, we can do this with:

```
cell = Cell[BoxData[
        FormBox[GridBox[{
        {
        RowBox[{
        RowBox[{"a", "+", "b", "+", "c"}], "\[AlignmentMarker]", "=", "d"}]},
        {
        RowBox[{"c", "\[AlignmentMarker]", "=", 
        RowBox[{"d", "-", "a", "-", "b"}]}]}
    }], TraditionalForm]], "DisplayMath"];
Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[cell]
```

The output is:

```tex
\begin{array}{c}
 a+b+c=d \\
 c=d-a-b
\end{array}
```

The function `` Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX `` is undocumented but the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TeX.html) does show how to use it under examples. It seems that the function doesn't do anything with the `\[AligmentMarker]`, but I'm sure we could make good use of them.

What we want to do is find any appearances of the `\[AligmentMarker]` and substitute them with "&". And if we did find some `\[AligmentMaker]`s then we use StringReplace to change "array" for "aligned". This is the output that I would like to end up with:

```tex
\begin{aligned}
 a+b+c&=d \\
 c&=d-a-b
\end{aligned}
```

Does anyone know how to create a wrapper function that does this? The main problem I'm having is replacing things in `cell`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the definition of cell as in the question we can define:

```
CellToTeX[cell_] := Module[{str},
  str = Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX@Replace[cell, {"\[AlignmentMarker]" -> "&"}, {-1}];
  StringReplace[str, {"\\&" -> "&", "array" -> "aligned"}]
]
```

Then when we use it we obtain:

```
CellToTeX[cell]
```

```
\begin{aligned}{c}
 a+b+c&=d \\
 c&=d-a-b
\end{aligned}
```

I'm still not so sure of how to define a rule to replace {c} or possibly many {cccc} for an empty string.

Comment: +1 for working to answer your own question, which BTW is a good one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. Now, if I could just manage to do the last part to complete it.

Comment: Regarding that (your last line) by chance is `"{" ~~ ("c" ..) ~~ "}" -> ""` all you're missing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you just answered the question. Could you write it as an answer and maybe explain a little about how you came up with it? I saw those type of rules but I would have never thought about using a rule like that...

Comment: You know it's funny- you're doing things with LaTeX I don't comprehend; it didn't occur to me that a simple replacement like this was holding you up.

Comment: I have to leave.  I'd be happy to write an introduction to *Mathematica* string replacements, but not right now.  Sorry I didn't give you a better answer, sooner!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no problem, I can wait. I'll probably need to add more string replacements rules in the future and I'll be referring to this question.