# $\TeX$ conversion, support for \hphantom

Tags: latex, custom-notation

I'm trying to write some $\TeX$ conversion for a tensor with an upper and a lower index, but I would like the lower index to be displaced to the right by the width of the upper index.  In (La)TeX I would write this as `W^I_{\hphantom{I} J}` ($W^I_{\hphantom{I} J}$).  I tried to use the `Invisible` Mathematica command, which seems to be the counterpart of $\TeX$'s `\phantom`, but instead of getting a space I get the upper index repeated as a lower index.

Here's the code I'm using now, which doesn't quite work:

```
w /: MakeBoxes[w[i_,j_],fmt_:StandardForm] := (*BUGGY*)
SubsuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[W,fmt], RowBox[{MakeBoxes[Invisible[i],fmt], MakeBoxes[j,fmt]}], MakeBoxes[i,fmt]]
```

This does work in the notebook front-end, but not when converting to (La)TeX.  What is the best way to achieve the result I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please let me know if I didn't understand correctly. What if you used a `Subscript` wrapping a `Superscript` instead of a `Subsuperscript`?

```
Subscript[Superscript[x, 4], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Its `TeXForm` gives `x^4{}_2`. Does that render as you want?

EDIT

Does this work?

```
yourTeXForm[expr_] := 
 Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[ToBoxes[expr], 
  "BoxRules" -> {StyleBox[t_, 
       op : OptionsPattern[]] /; (ShowContents /. 
         FilterRules[{op}, ShowContents]) === False :> 
     "\\hphantom{" <> Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[t] <> "}" }]

parseIndices[ind_List] := 
 Apply[Sequence, 
  Row /@ Riffle @@@ 
    Transpose@
     ReplaceList[
      Partition[ind, 2]\[Transpose], {b___, i : {__}, a___} :> {b, 
        Invisible /@ i, a}]]

ssp= Subsuperscript[x, parseIndices[Range[10]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
yourTeXForm[ssp]
```

> "x_{\hphantom{1}1\hphantom{3}3\hphantom{5}5\hphantom{7}7\\
>   hphantom{9}9}^{2\hphantom{2}4\hphantom{4}6\hphantom{6}8\hphantom{\
>   8}10\hphantom{10}}"

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing it this way, but I would say this is a hack and there should be something more appropriate built-in in Mathematica (but it looks like there isn't anything better at the moment).  I have to test this more, but it looks to me like the alignment of indices may come out wrong in some circumstances.

Comment: @SidiousLord, why does it feel like a hack? To me, that I'm not used to latex so much, inserting an invisible version of your superscript in the subscript feels more like a hack

Comment: As I said, in \TeX\ the placement of the indices will be a bit off.  For example, if I have a big symbol on which I want to put indices, if I follow your method I get $\int_{a}^{b}{}_{c}{}^{d}$ whereas with `\hphantom' I get $\int_{a \hphantom{b} c}^{\hphantom{a} b \hphantom{c} d}$.

Comment: @SidiousLord if you haven't, search for `ConversionRules` in the site, and check out if you can add your own rules to export some invisible box into a \hphantom. I haven't used `ConversionRules` yet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Rojo, I don't think `ConversionRules` is what is needed here since they just tell Mathematica how to export a styled cell to say TeX or HTML. I was having a similar [problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6155/877) in which mma didn't give me the correct TeX transformation. I think this is all done with `Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX` but I have no idea what this function wants so that we can get an `\hphantom` out of it.

Comment: @Rojo: No, the TeX `W^I{}_J` is different from the indicated construction with `\hphantom` in that the subscript of the former is displaced too far horizontally.

Comment: @jmlopez, see my edit, something like that?

Comment: @SidiousLord you too check the edit

Comment: @Rojo, That seems to be doing the job. I just found out about the option `"BoxRules"` but I still can't make it work correctly. Not sure if I should make it another question, but Sidious Lord question has gotten me to think more about how to write proper rules to convert from mms to tex. Consider the following: `RawBoxes@Convert`TeX`TeXToBoxes[
  "\\int_{a\\hphantom{b} c}^{\\hphantom{a} b\\hphantom{c} d}"]`. How would you make it write it correctly in mma? You know what, I am making it another question.

Comment: @Rojo, I have accepted your answer.  It seems that `Invisible` sets an option `ShowContents -> False` and then you use `"BoxRules"` to search for it and replace it with `\hphantom`.