# How can I export aligned equations to $\LaTeX$?

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, latex

Using Palettes ->  Writing Assistant -> Math Cells, you can enter aligned equations such as:

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[GridBox[{
    {GridBox[{
       {
        RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", 
         RowBox[{"expr", " ", "1"}]}]},
       {
        RowBox[{"=", 
         RowBox[{"expr", " ", "2"}]}]},
       {
        RowBox[{"=", 
         RowBox[{"expr", " ", "3"}]}]}
      },
      GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{"="}}}]}
   },
   GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{
        Scaled[0.96]}}}], TraditionalForm]]]], "Text"]
```

But saving as $\LaTeX$ yields equations that are unaligned and uncentered!

[image: sample]

I'm looking for a `SaveAsLatex` function that would correctly export *human readable* code for the following things:

1. (marker) Aligned Equations
2. Hyperlinks (refs, labels, etc...)
3. ItemNumbered cells
4. Centered math cells
5. Numbered and captioned tables/figures

Here is a [sample notebook](http://pastebin.com/9jg3Mkzx) to test your code.

Comment: What is an ItemNumbered cell?

Comment: It's a Cell style. Just go to Format -> Style -> Item Numbered. It uses a CounterBox to keep track of counts.

Comment: Would [Publicon](http://www.wolfram.com/products/publicon/) do what you want?

Comment: Does this [question's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6155/52) answer answer your question?